# Terminal emulator implementation - problems with repeated input

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, cmd, terminal-emulator

I am trying to implement a terminal emulator in Java. It is supposed to be able to host both cmd.exe on Windows and bash on Unix-like systems (I would like to support at least Linux and Mac OS X). The problem I have is that both `cmd.exe` and `bash` repeat on their standard output whatever I send to their standard input.

For example, in bash, I type "`ls`", hit enter, at which point the terminal emulator sends the input line to bash's stdin and flushes the stream. The process then outputs the input line again "`ls\n`" and then the output of the `ls` command.

This is a problem, because other programs apart from `bash` and `cmd.exe` don't do that. If I run, inside either bash, or `cmd.exe`, the command "`python -i`", the python interactive shell does not repeat the input in the way `bash` and `cmd.exe` does. This means a workaround would have to know what process the actual output came from. I doubt that's what actual terminal emulators do.

Running "`bash -i`" doesn't change this behaviour. As far as I know, `cmd.exe` doesn't have distinct "interactive" and "noninteractive" modes.

---

**EDIT:** I am creating the host process using the `ProcessBuilder` class. I am reading the stdout and stderr and writing to the stdin of the process using a technique similar to the [stream gobbler](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/puka/sourceCode/puka/StreamGobbler.java). I don't set any environment variables before I start the host process. The exact commands I use to start the processes are `bash -i` for bash and `cmd` for cmd.exe. I'll try to post minimal code example as soon as I manage to create one.

Comment: This seems relevant for `bash`: hide user input. http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/278/hide-password-entry-in-bournebash-shell-script/ Not sure how portable this is, though.

Comment: That's funny, `echo ls | bash` don't do anything like that.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't, even if I run that inside my terminal emulator. I'm guessing it has something to do with bash knowing that the input comes from a pipe.

Comment: Simply, that should not happen. You should clarify the question. What features do you use for creating the shell and redirect input and output? Can you isolate the issue into a small test program? In Unix, you would have to create a pseudo-terminal for most applications, and I doubt Java has a portable API for that.

Comment: @JuhoÖstman You're right, pseudo-terminals are the way to go in Unix. Other Java terminal emulators use native interface for that. That doesn't explain why `cmd.exe` does it, though. Apart from the code example, is there any more info I should provide?

Comment: In unix, you can use `stty -echo` command to turn off echo.  There's some ansi sequence you could use on Windows, but (1) I can't remember what it is; and (2) you can't guarantee that ansi.sys will be present on the target system.

Comment: On windows, you can invoke `cmd.exe` with `/c` parameter, which means "execute the following command and exit".  Not sure whether this would solve your problem.

Comment: @AleksG - `stty -echo` wouldn't help, because that gives a command to the terminal, or terminal emulator, which is what my program replaces. In the end, I would just be sending character sequences to my own program.

`cmd.exe /c` doesn't help at all. My program needs to fully replace the Windows console host.

Comment: @Honza Interactive Windows console programs often don't work well when connected to a pair of pipes rather than an actual console window. For example, it makes them default to full buffering and console-specific API calls e.g for changing colours will fail. Trouble is, MS don't provide a "pseudo console" interface that would allow to fully replace the builtin console. The best you can do is what http://console.sf.net does: have a hidden console window and grab its screen content using the ReadConsoleOutput() API. Obviously that's very different from what you need to do on Unix.

Comment: @Honza, `stty -echo` doesn't send a character sequence to the terminal, it adjusts a flag of the terminal driver. With Unix pseudo-terminals, you have three processes: the application (slave side of the PTY), the terminal driver and your terminal emulator (master side). You communicate with the terminal driver using a bidirectional stream. The application has a bidirectional stream to the terminal driver, and it can also adjust terminal driver flags. They affect echo, buffering and translation of characters, among others. If the echo flag is set, you get to read back any characters you send.

Comment: I see, so the bottom line is I have to use pseudo terminals. Apologies to @AleksG. Ok then, thanks every one for their input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Unix, run `stty -echo` to disable "local echo" (i.e. the shell repeating everything that you type). This is usually enabled so a user can edit what she types.

In your case, BASH must somehow allocate a pseudo TTY; otherwise, it would not echo every command. `set +x` would have a similar effect but then, you'd see `+ ls` instead of `ls` in the output.

With `cmd.exe` the command `@ECHO OFF` should achieve the same effect.

Just execute those after the process has been created and it should work.